# Installed nvidia driver, activated it, and now Unity is gone. No bars, menus, nothing

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg

I installed the nvidia driver (installed the ubuntu-x-swat ones, updated them, got the updates for them, installed bumblebee. I restarted everytime I did those steps, so no, i don't simply need to 'restart X'.  I tried to run things using bumblebee, but bumblebee was like "can't access GPU driver".  So I ran nvidia-settings, it said the drivers weren't in use, so I ran "sudo nvidia-xconfig", then restarted.

Now, my login screen looks differently than it did before: it asks me if I want to load: "GNOME, GNOME - no effects, Cairo Dock - GNOME, System Default, or Ubuntu" when I log in,

but *WORST OF ALL*: i no longer have any kind of GNOME/unity GUI. There are no title bars above any windows, no close/minimize/maximize buttons.  The unity bar is gone, and will not show up when I call it. And the top status bar is also no longer there.
[image: I can't close any windows or open anything that I don't know the command for]

**UPDATE:**  I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu, and doing the following:

1) Installed the linux sources and headers. (These are required to build the driver)

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
```

2) Add a PPA containing recent drivers: (How recent are these?)

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

3) Add the Stable Bumblebee Releases PPA and install Bumblebee using the proprietary NVIDIA driver:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

And now things work. My graphics card is by default off. If I run
    glxspheres
I get ~50fps, and if I
    optirun glxspheres
I get ~150 fps.  When I run nvidia-settings or optirun nvidia-settings, I get this:
[image: not many options]

Comment: I recommend moving your solution to be an Answer that you accept. Thanks for following up with your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the nvidia drivers that cause this problem.  It seems to be a problem with the accelerated drivers and how unity/X tries to use the GPU.  Reverting to the nouveau drivers should fix the problems, or you can try nvidia-current or nvidia-current-updates.  I haven't had a lot of luck so far with the newer 304.x driver modules.

Comment: How do I revert to the nouveau drivers? What is the terminal command to do so?